# Async search event handling

Tags: php, javascript, performance, search, autocomplete

I have a web-based search input. At each onkeyup event, an async request is made, from the client with JavaScript, to a PHP document that returns the search response - then the JS takes the search response and writes it to the client. This part works fine.

However, my issue is when a user types their search term faster than the system can respond.

Let's say a user - that types fast - is doing a search for the word `super`. The user types `s` (and a search is done for `s`), while the search is being performed and written for `s` the user types `u`, and now a search for `su` is queued up. Then, this very fast typing user types a `p`, while the initial search for `s` is finishing up, and now searches for `su` and `sup` are queued.

If a user types slowly, there is no issue and my search tool can respond to each keyup without having to queue up search requests. However, if a user types very fast, they will see several search result refreshes flash before them after they finish typing their search term because the script is finishing up items in the queue.

How could I improve my code to improve the user experience?

For example, how would you script this so that any queued items, other than the last one made are dropped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a single timeout (called ***debouncing***):

> *"Debouncing means to coalesce several temporally close signals into one signal."*

```
var timer;
function keyup() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    search(this.value);
    timer = null;
  }, timer ? 50 : 1);
}
```

This code means that if the user is typing too fast (delta <50ms in this case) the action won't queue up, but the newest always overwrites the previous ones.

There is another approach (called ***throttling***):

> *"Throttling is the reduction in rate of a repeating event."*

```
var timer;
function keyup() {
  if (!timer)
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      search(this.value);
      timer = null;
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

Finally you can fetch more data at a time to get around latency issues.
See this post to see how *Flickr* does it: **[Building Fast Client-side Searches](http://code.flickr.com/blog/2009/03/18/building-fast-client-side-searches/)**

Also make sure to use some kind of caching (APC/memcache) depending on how frequently your data changes. This can greatly reduce stress on your database.

Comment: I've thought about using a timeout. And it's possible that will be the best way. However, it's not my first choice because I want to make the search as fast as possible. ... Also, I like the Flickr blog link. It looks like they were able to arrange their search with no query delay.

Comment: Well it depends on a lot of things, e.g: your table size, expected latency, distribution of data. I've updated the first code to start searching immediately if the key was hit for the first time.

Comment: You can also combine the two: e.g: below 3 letters you use debounce, but after you've reached 3 you grab the full dataset (matching those 3 letters) and continue searching on the client-side.

Comment: I like the idea of debouncing with shorter search queries, but querying client-side with longer queries (and thus a smaller dataset). That could work well.

Comment: "Also make sure to use some kind of caching (APC/memcache) depending on how frequently your data changes. This can greatly reduce stress on your database." --- My front-end doesn't access a database. Data comes from a web service. I have over 10 million records available (and this number will need to scale up to possibly 10 times that size), and even more permutations of result sets. I'm not sure how you would memcache this (or if you'd even want to). If you have ideas about caching though, let me know, and I'll open another question about it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution is a timer for "onkeyup".

A sample with jQuery:

```
var timer = null;
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if(timer!=null){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    // wait and call in 150 ms
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // call here your search function!
        ....
    }, 150);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a few have mentioned, you can use a timeout to slow the pace of fetching results from the server. Note, though, that this will still show a small delay for the user.

*If* the data is a candidate for being fetched and stored on page load, you can provide a much faster auto-complete solution by simply retrieving it from the client-side memory.

Comment: My dataset contains around 10 million rows - so storing in client-side memory would be challenging.

Comment: It's a concept that's not entirely far-fetched though. As a user enters more search characters, the number of matches diminishes. So it may be possible to prefetch potential matches to client memory.