# How to handle only last keyup event in search functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got search input on my web site. When user type a letter in it, ajax request displaying some content in result is performed. What i want to achieve is create ajax request only for last keyup event when user writes fast. I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293817/async-search-event-handling) but it doesnt work for me, i recieve 'TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined'. Here is my code:

```
var timeout;

$(function() {
  $('body').on('keyup', '.teryt-search-input', terytSearchAjax);
});

function terytSearchAjax(e) {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
      var el = $(this).parent().next('.list-group');
      el.children('.loader').removeClass('hidden');
      el.children('.content').load($(this).attr('action'), { needle: $(this).val() }, function(){
        el.children('.loader').addClass('hidden');
        el.children('.extra-content').removeClass('hidden');
      });
      timeout = null;
    }
  }, timeout ? 50 : 1);
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Or please write other solution for this case.

Comment: As you're already using jQuery have a look at [$.debounce](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html) from Ben Alman

Comment: in the setTimeout, replace all of `$(this).val()` with `$('.teryt-search-input').val()`. your `this` is not reference to your input when it called in the setTimeout scope.

Comment: (Just to add to @Andreas' comment, the excellent $.debounce plugin doesn't depend on jQuery – without jQuery the plugin works as `Cowboy.debounce`)

Comment: No need for another plugin for the 10 lines of code task.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error lies in $(this).
Shouldn't that be e.target?

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/sBb3A/

```
var timeout = 1000;
var timer;

$("#input").on("keyup", function(event) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        Go(event.target);
    }, timeout);


});

function Go(input) {
    alert($(input).val());
}
```

**edit**  Oops.. just read Hereblur's comment.